# how to make spring starter project(spring boot) for Java version 6 in eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

i want make spring boot project in eclipse using project wizard.

select **Spring - Spring Starter Project**

can't select java 6 option.

[image: Project Wizard Spring Starter Project]

Why is there no choice **Java Version 6**?

my eclipse and sts plugin version below:

**Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)**

**Installed STS Plugin:**
[image: STS Plugin version]

can i display **Java Version 6** in **Project Wizard**?

or make project for **Java Version 8** first can migration to **Java Version 6**?

Comment: I'm curious of why you want to use Java 6?

Comment: @MC Emperor The client environment is only available for java 6.

Comment: @JYL i would consider if you REALLY need to use java6 for that. I would recommend in most cases, if not in every case to still use atleast java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.5 is the last release version which supports java 6.

For Spring Boot 2 you should have Java 8 or higher version.

So it is possible to run Spring Boot 1.5 on Java 6. See documentation [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-java-6).

Comment: So, first of all, should I create a project with java version 8 and convert it by referring to the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-java-6)?

Comment: @JYL curious to know why you want to use java 6 now? ...and if you want to use java 6 only then YES you will have to do this.

Comment: the client server environment is only available for java 6. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. The current stable version of Spring Boot (2.1.0 at time of writing) requires Java 8 or 9, according to [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html).

Comment: cannot use spring boot 1.x(1.5 or under) for project wizard?
i referenced [link howto-use-java-6](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-java-6).

Answer (score 0):

Actually , There are various version jars of spring-boot available. But still your requirement to with Java 6. Why? I think atleast you should go for java 1.7 (which is also now not recommended by oracle to start a new Project ).

If you talk about only spring-boot. then `Spring-boot 2` is latest and it actually design over java 8. So, at-least `java8` is required if you want to create a project using Spring starter here you go.[Spring Starter Project Creation](https://start.spring.io/)

> `Spring-boot-1.5.0` for which you should think about.

This is last version of spring boot which actually supports 1.6 or later (work also on java8 but some additional stuffs like spring-data, security, cloud etc... API's have some deprecated methods or class).

Now if you have only a option to work with `java6` then you should create a project and take care of dependency in your build Tool (**Maven/Gradle/Ant**).